# Limit of Sequence of Distributions

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

> Define
>
> $$f_k=\sum_{n=1}^{k}\delta_n$$
>
> Show that the limit of $f_k$ exists as a distribution. Find a locally integrable function $F$ such that the distributional derivative of $F$ is the limit of $f_k$

This is what I've managed so far:

$\delta_n$ is the distributional derivative of $H(x-n)$

let $F=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}H(x-n)= 
\begin{cases}
\lfloor x \rfloor  & \text{if $x\geq0$} \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

$-\langle F, \phi'\rangle=-\int_{\mathbb{R}} (\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}H(x-n))\phi'(x) \ dx = -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\int_{\mathbb{R}}H(x-n)\phi'(x) \ dx)$

Integrate by parts:

$-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\int_{\mathbb{R}}H(x-n)\phi'(x) \ dx) = -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-\int_{\mathbb{R}}\delta_n\phi(x) \ dx \ + \ [H(x-n)\phi(x)]_{x=-\infty}^{x=\infty})$

The boundary terms go to $0$ because of compact support

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\int_{\mathbb{R}}\delta_n\phi(x) \ dx) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\delta_n)\phi(x) \ dx=\langle f_k,\phi \rangle$

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: you mean $\sum_{n=1}^k \delta(x-n)$. Then $\delta(x)$ is the derivative of which function ? What does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty g(x-n)$ look like ?

Comment: $\delta(x)$ is the distributional derivative of $g(x) = 1_{x > 0}$. Then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty g(x-n)$ is almost $  \lfloor x \rfloor$